# Problem with displaying data that I want to delete with many to many relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I have many to many relationship between users and products table and I set up a view (welcome.blade.php) that when I click on the product name, which is a link, it is supposed to redirect me to page where my delete form is so I can delete that particular product, but I get 404 not found page. I suspect that error is somewhere in my routes but I can't seem to find the problem. Also when I click on some product my url says project/destroy/1 which I think is good. Here is my code:

web.php:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('/store', 'HomeController@store')->name('store');
Route::delete('/destroy/{$id}', 'HomeController@destroy')->name('destroy');
```

destroy.blade.php:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form action="destroy/{{ $product->id }}" method="POST">
     @csrf
     @method('DELETE')
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

welcome.blade.php:

```
@if($products)
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Owner Of The Product</th>
        <th>Created At</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($products as $product)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('destroy', $product->id) }}">{{ $product->files }}</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach ($product->users as $user) {{ $user->name }}
                @endforeach
            </td>
            <td>{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($product->created_at)) }}</td>
        </tr>
     @endforeach
     </tbody>
     </table>
 @endif
```

HomeController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function destroy(Product $product)
    {
        $product->users()->detach();
        $product->delete();
        return view('destroy');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nearly there, you just have a step too many.

Good call on the form and using the delete method, this is absolutely what you are supposed to do

However where you are going wrong is in using the link to go to a separate page with the form on to delete.  You are better using a little javascript so the link submits a hidden form from the link.

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('delete-form-{{$product->id}}').submit();}">{{ $product->files }}</a>
<form id="delete-form-{{$product->id}}" action="{{ route('destroy', ['id' => $product->id]) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    @csrf
    @method('delete')
</form>
```

You can do the method you have but you need an additional route::get request to a page that loads the form and then you can submit the form on that page to delete.

Comment: I put this javascript and form on my welcome page, I am just little confused, if you can elaborate to me where does this additional get route supposed to go exactly?

Comment: You only need the additional route if you want to go to a separate page to delete. If you use the code above you wont need an extra route

Answer (score 1):

You defined the following route in your file.

```
Route::delete('/destroy/{$id}', 'HomeController@destroy')->name('destroy');
```

This creates a **DELETE** route. **DELETE** routes are meant to be accessed by APIs. Links in anchor tags use **GET** routes. Clicking on

```
<a href="{{ route('destroy' , $product->id) }}">{{ $product->files }}</a>
```

makes the router try and match **GET** `/destroy/{$id}` which is not defined, so it throws either an exception if debug is on or a 404 if not. You can see this in action by looking at the network tab of your browser's developer console.

Unless you add another **GET** route, you'll keep getting 404s.

```
Route::get('/destroy/{$id}', 'HomeController@destroy')->name('product.destroy-form');
```

will make the following link work.

```
<a href="{{ route('product.destroy-form' , $product->id) }}">{{ $product->files }}</a>
```

Also, in the destroy method you're returning the view without passing any variables but in `destroy.blade.php` you seem to be using `$product`. Don't forget to add it!

Comment: I changed the route and the link like you told me and I added   return view('destroy')->with('product', $product); but it still shows me 404 not found page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in your browser's dev console while you click on the link? Is it returning a 404 to the correct url?

Comment: Request URL: http://admin.devel/destroy/1  Request Method: GET  Status Code: 404 Not Found  . This is what is returning, it is correct url.

Comment: Delete routes are not only for APi's, part of the restful ideas behind Laravel Routes is you can call patch, put and delete.

Comment: Okay, next see if that route appears in your console when you run php artisan route:list

@ColinMD Yes, through a hack. putting [at]method in your form won't change the fact your browser will make a GET or a POST request. It just tells Laravel's router "Let's pretend this was a PUT, PATCH, DELETE request".

Comment: @IGF which is why Laravel was designed the way it is, to spoof the correct method.  Why would it not appear in the route list?

Comment: Available Router Methods
The router allows you to register routes that respond to any HTTP verb:
Route::get($uri, $callback);
Route::post($uri, $callback);
Route::put($uri, $callback);
Route::patch($uri, $callback);
Route::delete($uri, $callback);
Route::options($uri, $callback);

Comment: Sorry, that comment came a bit confusing. I was trying to ask @Marko if the route appeared in his list since he's still getting a 404.

Comment: @IGP Yes, there is route on my list,   GET|HEAD | destroy/{$id}          | product.destroy-form | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@destroy

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because to delete a product using a  new page the first thing to do is navigate to that page which you are not doing. You are instead going directly to the delete function using this

```
Route::delete('/destroy/{$id}', 'HomeController@destroy')->name('destroy');
```

You need to define a route that lets you go to that page first which u can do by creating a route like this:

```
Route::get('/delete/{$id}', 'HomeController@delete')->name('delete');
```

You should create a new function delete in the HomeController that just returns the destroy.blade.php. Something like this.

```
$product= Product::find($id);
    return view('destroy')->with('product', $product);
```

where $id is the product id and Product is the model that you are using.